# How to solve $\int^1_0 (1+7x)^{1/3}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I worked through $\int^1_0 (1+7x)^{1/3}dx$ and I got $\frac{3}{4}+C$ for the answer. However, I forgot about the exponent when I found the difference of the sides of the integral.

I am retrying it, but I've realized I don't know how to find a number to the power of $\frac{4}{3}$. Also, when I went over this with Symbolab, once u-substitution had been applied, the integral changed to $\int^8_1$ for some reason. I'm sure it's the key to solving this, but I have no idea why that's even allowed.

My textbook and Symbolab both say the answer is $\frac{45}{28}$.

Here are the steps I took. Please let me know what I got wrong.

> $\int^1_0 (1+7x)^{1/3}dx$

Let $u=1+7x$

Then $du=7dx$ and $dx=\frac{1}{7}du$

so $\int^1_0u^{1/3}\frac{1}{7}du=\frac{1}{7}\int^1_0u^{1/3}$

$$\frac{1}{7}\int^1_0u^{1/3}$$

$$=\frac{1}{7}[\frac{u^{4/3}}{4/3}|^1_0]$$ $$=\frac{1}{7}[\frac{3u^{4/3}}{4}|^1_0]$$

$$=\frac{1}{7}[\frac{3(1+7(1))^{4/3}}{4}-\frac{3(1+7(0))^{4/3}}{4}]$$

$$=\frac{1}{7}[\frac{3(1+7)^{4/3}}{4}-\frac{3(1+0)^{4/3}}{4}]$$

This is as far as I can get.

Comment: When you use $u$-substitution, you also need to change the limits of integration. Since $u = 1 + 7x$, integrating $x$ from 0 to 1 is the same as integrating $u$ from 1 to 8 (plug in the values for $x$).

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, how can I tell what to change the limits to?

Comment: In general, whenever you change variables you need to change the limits. If you are integrating with respect to $x$ from $a$ to $b$, and make the substitution $u = f(x)$, then the problem becomes integrating with respect to $u = f(x)$ from $a' = f(a)$ to $b' = f(b)$. For example consider $\int_0^12x dx$ (which of course is 1). If I make the substitution $u = 2x$, $du = 2dx$, then I need to integrate from $2\cdot 0 = 0$ to $2\cdot 1 = 2$ to get $$\int_0^12x dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^12x 2dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2u du = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}u^2\right]_0^2 = 1.$$ This would not work otherwise.

Comment: I agree that OP should have changed the limits of integration when changing the variable of integration to $u$ (and should not have dropped "$du$"), but I think that, when evaluating the integral, OP actually did evaluate properly; e.g., $(1+7(1))^{4/3}$ rather than $1^{4/3}$; see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't change your limits. When $x=0,$ then $u=1,$ and when $x=1,$ then $u=8.$

Comment: Thank you, how can I tell what to change the limits to?

Comment: @LuminousNutria You let $u = 1 + 7x$.  Substitute for $x$ to find the corresponding value of $u$.

Comment: @LuminousNutria Glad to help. I find someone has answered on my behalf. The substitution you use must be used to completely transform the parameters of the integral -- from the integration variable to the integrand to the limits, not just some of them, but all.

Answer (score 1):

You got $\dfrac{1}{7}\left[\dfrac{3(1+7)^{4/3}}{4}-\dfrac{3(1+0)^{4/3}}{4}\right].$

Note that $(1+7)^{4/3}=8^{4/3}=(8^{1/3})^4=2^4=16$ and $(1+0)^{4/3}=1^{4/3}=1,$

so you actually got the correct answer:  $\dfrac17\left[\dfrac{3\times16}4-\dfrac{3\times1}4\right]=\dfrac17\dfrac{45}4=\dfrac{45}{28}.$

Comment: OP wrote " I don't know how to find a number to the power of 4/3"; hence my answer

Comment: Thank you! This really helps.